# "tool use by animals" or "tool use in animals"?

Tags: prepositions

"tool use by animals" is the title of a wikipedia page, "tool use in animals" gets more google hits and is the title of a book (that, however, has been written by Germans). Are both phrases correct? Is one of them preferable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either will be acceptable in the correct context.

When considering "tool use" as a characteristic you want to say "tool use in animals." When considering "tool use" as an activitiy you want to say "tool use by animals."

Comment: Thanks. But then "tool use in animals" would be the better title of the Wikipedia page, wouldn't it?

Comment: You mean the web page you linked to? Oh... (big wide grin)

Comment: I mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tool_use_by_animals

Comment: I think this "characteristic / activity" distinction is a bit fanciful. To the extent that the choice of preposition makes a *slight* difference, it's that *tool use **by** animals* more strongly implies that the animals are ***conscious agents*** (***choosing*** to use tools), whereas *tool use **in** animals* tends to "objectify" the animals as simply representing an ***environment*** within which tool use occurs.